# "ls -lh" directories reported size : linux vs cifs mounted drives

Tags: linux, rsync, cifs

From a linux box, I recently mounted a Windows share using cifs.

The intend was to "locally" use rsync to backup my windows machine. 
The command line used to mount the Windows drive is something like:

```
mount \\192.168.1.74\share /cifs1 -t cifs -o noserverino,iocharset=utf8,ro
```

Please also note that the drive attached to the linux box is formatted ntfs.

When doing a sample backup, rsync was always re-copying the directories (names), but not the files. After looking more closely at the "ls -lh " output at both ends, I noticed that on the linux side the size of the directory level is always 0:

```
TTT-Admin@1080-Router:/tmp/mnt/RT-1080/tmp# ls -lh
drwxrwxrwx    1 TTT-Admi root           0 Feb  8 12:14 DeltaCopy
```

but the size of the directory level on the cifs side was always different from 0:

```
TTT-Admin@1080-Router:/cifs1/temp/Rsync-Packages# ls -lh
drwxr-xr-x    1 TTT-Admi root        8.0K Feb  8 12:14 DeltaCopy
```

This difference explains why rsync was always recopying directories, but not recopying the folders(which was correct, folder sizes and time stamps being the same on both ends).

EDIT: the rsync command is:

```
> rsync -av /cifs1/Temp/Rsync-Packages/DeltaCopy /mnt/RT-1080/tmp/rsync
 -av /cifs1/Temp/Rsync-Packages/DeltaCopy /mnt/RT-1080/tmp/
```

Is a directory supposed to "have a size" or not ? What should I do to solve this discrepancy ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic and is best suited for `unix.stackexchange.com` !

Comment: Great, but for my information, what is the intent of this forum ? thanks.